# C++ : two types of return | templates

Tags: c++, templates, types, return

I have a function that should return an object of class A if i is positive, return an integer else.
This is a strong simplified example, and i can not use overloading !

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T& function(int i){
    T res;
    if (i>0){
        A res = 1;
    }
    else{
        int res = 5;
    }
    return res;
}


int main(){
    A res1 = function(5);
    int res2 = function(-5;)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you want this?

Comment: Are the function arguments compile-time constant expressions?

Comment: What happens if `i` isn't known until run-time?

Comment: I see know that it is impossible to solve my problem this way i need to find an other way, thank you all anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Types are static, determined when the code is compiled, so you can't have a different return type depending on a run-time value. A function can only return one type.

One option is to use a *discriminated union*; a union of the different types you want to support, along with an enumerated value to indicate which type is active. This is quite tricky to implement if you want to support general class types, so you might want to look at Boost's [Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/variant.html) library. For example:

```
boost::variant<int,T> function(int i) {
    if (i>0)
        return A{1};
    else
        return int{5};
}

int main() {
    A res1 = boost::get<A>(function(5));
    int res2 = boost::get<int>(funtion(-5);
}
```

Another option might be to provide a set of callback functions for different types, and handle the value there rather than returning it. For example:

```
template <typename Callback>
void function(int i, Callback & callback)
    if (i>0)
        callback(A{1});
    else
        callback(int{5});
}

struct MyCallback {
    void operator()(A const &) {/* do something with A */}
    void operator()(int)       {/* do something with int */}
};

int main() {
    MyCallback callback;
    function(5, callback);  // calls callback for A
    function(-5, callback); // calls callback for int
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is impossible. Your function can only have one return type. You could pass in an A variable and an integer variable by reference and have one or the other set by the function but that's the closest you're going to be able to get. I'm rather unsure of what you are trying to accomplish though.

Comment: Not actually impossible.  Just difficult and requiring some extra work.  I too would like to know what he actually is trying to do.  Because this smells like a bad solution to an easy problem.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity just speculating now, but it may be that the OP is used to "dynamically typed" languages, e.g. LUA where this sort of thing is trivial.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity - I don't see how it would be possible besides returning a wrapper object or something like that, I don't know if I'd really consider that a variable return type though. Unless there's another way?

Comment: To do it the way he wants to do it is impossible, sure.

Answer (score 0):

C++ simply does not support this.

A better solution would be:

```
bool function(int i, int &intResult, A &AResult)
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        AResult = A(1);
        // Or whatever other code you need to place the result in AResult
        return true;
    }
    intResult = 5;
    return false;
}
```

You need to pass both an int and an A to receive the possible return values, and by inspecting the bool that's returned you know which one was filled in.